# Assigning bs4.element.Tag to a variable and modifying it

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have `bs4.element.Tag`(`OriginalElement`) which iam assigning it a variable and then trying to remove some tags in the assigned variable and then using the original tag element(`OriginalElement`) to assign it to another variable and then trying to remove some other elements but the first change is been reflected in the original tag element(`OriginalElement`) and I would like to know is there an alternative way to fix this?

Code snippet :

```py
beforeEl = OriginalElement
if(beforeEl('ins')):
    [r.extract() for r in beforeEl('ins')]
    writeFile.write("Before    :: "+str(beforeEl.text).replace("\n"," ").replace("\t"," ")+"\n")
afterEl = OriginalElement
if(afterEl('del')):
    [q.extract() for q in afterEl('del')]
    writeFile.write("After     :: "+str(afterEl.text).replace("\n"," ").replace("\t"," ")+"\n")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dirty workaround could be

Code snippet :

```py
beforeEl = bs4.BeautifulSoup(str(OriginalElement),features="lxml")
if(beforeEl('ins')):
    [r.extract() for r in beforeEl('ins')]
    writeFile.write("Before    :: "+str(beforeEl.text).replace("\n"," ").replace("\t"," ")+"\n")
afterEl = bs4.BeautifulSoup(str(OriginalElement),features="lxml")
if(afterEl('del')):
    [q.extract() for q in afterEl('del')]
    writeFile.write("After     :: "+str(afterEl.text).replace("\n"," ").replace("\t"," ")+"\n")
```

But I would like to know an effective way to fix this.